# Ember extend component computed property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a parent component Parent and Child component that extends Parent.
In Parent there is a computed property `items` that returns array. Is there a way to have `items` in Child component that will return both elements from parent array and additional elements e.g.

Parent:

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  items: computed(function() {
    return ['a', 'b'];
  })
})
```

Child:

```
Parent.extend({
  items: computed(function() {
    // I want to add some more elements to parent property
    // so this should return ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    return this.get('items').concat(['c', 'd']);
  })
});
```

Currently I get `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Use `_super`:

```
Parent.extend({
  items: computed(function() {
    // I want to add some more elements to parent property
    // so this should return ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    return this._super('items').concat(['c', 'd']);
  })
});
```

Here is a working [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8a916d42d630d0a7ca2fa09b1ed5aea8?openFiles=components.my-sub-component.js%2C).